# Set of Density Operators with Separable Eigenbasis

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Let $\mathbb{H}^A$ and $\mathbb{H}^B$ be finite dimensional Hilbert spaces. Consider the set $S$ of all bipartite density operators $\rho \in D(\mathbb{H}^A \otimes \mathbb{H}^B)$ such that every eigenspace of $\rho$ has an orthonormal basis consisting of separable vectors, i.e. vectors of the form $| e_j \rangle \otimes | f_k \rangle$ for some $| e_j \rangle \in \mathbb{H}^A$ and $| f_k \rangle \in \mathbb{H}^B$. **Are there any equivalent characterizations or useful properties of this set $S$?**

For instance, every $\rho \in S$ can be written as

$$\rho = \sum_{j,k} p_{j,k} | e_j \rangle \otimes | f_k \rangle \langle e_j | \otimes \langle f_k |,$$

where the $p_{j,k}$ are probabilities and the $| e_j \rangle \otimes | f_k \rangle$ are the separable orthonormal eigenvectors of $\rho$. Then every $\rho \in S$ is separable. However, from [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13031/what-separable-rho-only-admit-separable-pure-decompositions-with-more-than), it appears that not every separable state belongs to $S$. **Can we characterize which separable states belong to $S$?**

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399675/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-separable-pure-states-needed-to-decompose-arbitrar) seems to be related.